# Why cannot `ftp` program read a file in /tmp directory?

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, vsftpd

While making an automated ftp upload script, I noticed a very strange behaviour of `ftp` program: if I want to send a file which belongs to `/tmp` directory, `ftp` will always fail and give an error message: `cannot create file`.

See this:

```
^_^ ~ > touch /tmp/file1

^_^ ~ > touch file2

^_^ ~ > ftp <server>
Connected to <server> (<server ip>).
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (<server:username>): <username>
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.

ftp> put /tmp/file1
local: /tmp/file1 remote: /tmp/file1
227 Entering Passive Mode (<ip>).
553 Could not create file.

ftp> put file2
local: file2 remote: file2
227 Entering Passive Mode (<ip>).
150 Ok to send data.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp>
```

What is wrong with `ftp` reading a file from `/tmp`?

There is no SELinux or AppArmor on the server nor on the `ftp` client.

Comment: Does the `/tmp` directory exist on the `ftp` server and do you have access to it?  Can you `cd` into both the remote and local `/tmp` directories and `put file1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn’t reading the file from `/tmp` –– read the error message: “553 Could not create file.”  When you say

> `put` *a_single_file_name*

that is equivalent to

> `put`  *single_file_name*   *that_same_file_name_again*

So `put /tmp/file1` is equivalent to `put /tmp/file1 /tmp/file1`, and this fails if the FTP server doesn’t have a writable `/tmp` directory configured. 
Try `put /tmp/file1 file1`, or maybe `put /tmp/file1 ./file1`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you run `ftp` you are connected to a remote machine. Use the `lcd` to change directories on your local machine; `cd` will change directories on the remote machine.  In your case

```
lcd /tmp
put file1
lcd <to original directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls -l` to view the permissions on the folder. Does the user you authenticate as have write access to that directory? If not, you need to use `chmod` to ensure that it does, or it will never work.

Often, FTP accounts have limited access to areas close to `/`  In fact, some systems are set up so they can ONLY write to `/home/ftpUserName`

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle this in FTP is to use the `cd` command to change the *remote* directory, while using the `lcd` (local `cd`) command to change the *local* directory (obviously a shell escape from FTP won't help (MS-Windows excepted, maybe)).
Then just `put` your files from the local directory to the remote directory.